# Is it possible to send all new windows to a specified virtual desktop in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

So I use virtual desktops primarily for RDP -- the first desktop is the host computer and each new desktop is a different full screen RDP session. This works out very well, but when an alert dialog pops up on the host computer and I'm focused on a full screen virtual desktop the alert message is effectively hidden.

What'd i'd like to do if possible is send all new windows to the first virtual desktop, regardless of which desktop I am looking at. Is this a feature that is supported by windows, or are there any utilities that can do something like this (I'm also open to open source utilities with basic Virtual desktop management functionality, If it can move windows between desktops I think I can make it do what I want)